# SQL NEWBIE, LIKE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL could someone correct me this query ?!

```
CREATE TABLE AVION
(
    AV int IDENTITY(100, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    AVMARQUE varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    AVTYPE varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    CAP int CHECK (CAP BETWEEN 100 AND 600),
    LOC varchar(30)
)

CREATE TABLE PILOTE
(
    PIL int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    PILNOM varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    ADR varchar(30)
)

CREATE TABLE VOLE
(
    VOL varchar(5) PRIMARY KEY CHECK(VOL LIKE 'IT'[1,9][0,9][0,9]),
    PIL int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PILOTE(PIL),
    AV int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AVION(AV),
    VD varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    VA varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    HD TIME CHECK (HD BETWEEN '00:00' AND '23:59'),
    HA TIME CHECK (HA BETWEEN '00:00' AND '23:59')
)
```

- **VOL** is a string with 5 characters that start with 'IT' and the rest are numbers first number is different then 0
- **PIL** FOREIGN KEY FROM `PILOTE` TABLE
- **AV** FOREIGN KEY FROM `AVION` TABLE
- **VD** is the departure city
- **VA** is the destination city
- **HD** is the departure time
- **HV** is the arrival time

Comment: please remove the unused db tag ..

Comment: Correct what? Please ask a specific question, include specific errors, etc.

Comment: mysql or SQL-Server?

Comment: VOL table is incorrect

Comment: Jens sql-SERVER

Comment: 'VOL varchar(5) PRIMARY KEY CHECK(VOL LIKE 'IT'[1,9][0,9][0,9]),
        PIL int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PILOTE(PIL),
        AV int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AVION(AV),
        VD varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        VA varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        HD TIME CHECK (HD BETWEEN '00:00' AND '23:59'),
        HA TIME CHECK (HA BETWEEN '00:00' AND '23:59')'

Comment: VOL varchar(5) PRIMARY KEY CHECK(VOL LIKE 'IT'[1,9][0,9][0,9]) this one is broke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be as simple as moving the quotes. Try:

```
LIKE 'IT[1,9][0,9][0,9]'
```